# Howto persist MongoDB - data of a running Docker container in a new image?

Tags: mongodb, docker

i have a running Mongo DB Container called xyz from offical Mongo Image. i created the container with `docker run -d -p 21707:21707 mongo` 
In this container i created 2 collections with sample data.

Now i want to extract this container in a new image on dockerhub.

I used `docker commit` and created a new image, pushed it on the docker hub. If i pull the image on a other system and create a new container from this image, there are no data like in my origin container xyz.

After research i found out that the mongo image could used with a volume, but i missed this step in the past... I think the container use /data/db as standard volume(`docker inspect`), on commit this volume is not attached to the new image?!

Also i tried `docker export/import` with the same problem mentioned above!

Now my Question, how could i reach to migrate this "xyz" running container with my sample data in a new image/container? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: PS. i know that i could use "mongoexport" and then restore with "mongoimport" but the problem is, i have to create new users in the mongodb too...

Answer (score 7):

> I used docker commit and created a new image, pushed it on the docker hub. If i pull the image on a other system and create a new container from this image, there are no data like in my origin container xyz.

The mongo docker image writes its data into a [*volume*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/). As a result, those data won't be saved to a new docker image created with `docker commit`. `docker export` won't produce your data for the same reason.

> how could i reach to migrate this "xyz" running container with my sample data in a new image/container?

What you want is either:

- create a new container re-using the first container's volume → see [`--volumes-from`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems)
- save the first container's volume data into a directory on your docker host, and create a new container *mounting* this directory into the container → the `docker run` [`-v` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems)

Also, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331651/how-can-i-backup-a-docker-container-with-its-data-volumes/26339848) might help you figure out volumes.

Comment: i tried this: 1.docker run --volumes-from 6213f69189bc -v $(pwd):/backup node  tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /data/db

2. i got a backup.tar in my folder
3. create a new container ddec84b89544 from my docker hub image.
4. docker run --volumes-from ddec84b89544 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /data/db && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar --> this completed without errors...
5. link a other mongo container to ddec84b89544 and check the collections -> there where no collections :/

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to make an image to test things around authentication and I has the same issue. I solved it this way:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mongo

COPY setup.sh /
RUN chmod +x /setup.sh
RUN /setup.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
CMD ["--auth", "--dbpath=/containerdb"]
```

**setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir containerdb

mongod --auth --dbpath=/containerdb &

until mongo admin --eval 'db.createUser({"user":"root", "pwd":"password", "roles": [ "root" ] })'
do
  echo 'Mongo not yet ready, waiting 1 sec until retry'
  sleep 1
done

mongod --shutdown --dbpath=/containerdb
```

Bim! When you run this image you have a mongodb with authentication activated and a root user.
The key is to workaround the VOLUME in the base Dockerfile by storing the data somewhere else.