# Trying to create a Docker image with a MongoDB database, but the container does not have it even though it loaded successfully

Tags: mongodb, docker

The data in the database is intended to be surfaced by an API in another container. Previously, I have successfully loaded the database during run using [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33397913/1454087). However, my database is quite large (10gb) and ideally I would not have to load the database again each time I start a new container. I want the database to be loaded on build. To accomplish this, I tried the following for my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:4.0.6-xenial

COPY dump /data/dump

RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log \
&& mongorestore /data/dump \
&& mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('db').createUser({user:'user',pwd:'pwd',roles:['readWrite']})" \
&& mongod --shutdown
```

I expected the database to be in the container when I ran this image, but it was not, nor does the user exist. However, the log file /var/log/mongod.log indicates that the database loaded successfully as far as I can tell. Why did this not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto persist MongoDB - data of a running Docker container in a new image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753792/howto-persist-mongodb-data-of-a-running-docker-container-in-a-new-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official mongo Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) writes the database data in a [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

At run time (thus in a docker container), keep in mind that files written to volumes do not end up written on the container file system. This is done to persist your data so that it survives container deletion, but more importantly in the context of database, for performance reasons. To have good I/O performances with disks, disk operations must be done on a volume, not on the container file system itself.

At build time (thus when creating a docker image), if you happen to have `RUN`/`ADD`/`COPY` directives in your Dockerfile write files to a location which is already declared as a volume, those files will be discarded. However, if you write the files to a directory in your Dockerfile, and only after you declare that directory as a volume, then those the volume will keep those files unless you start your container specifying a volume with the `docker run -v` option.

This means that in the case your own Dockerfile is built `FROM mongo`, the `/data` location is already declared as a volume. Writing files to that location is pointless.

### What can be done?

#### Make you own mongo image from scratch

Knowing how volumes works, you could copy the contents from the Dockerfile of the official mongo Docker image and insert a `RUN`/`ADD`/`COPY` directive to write the  files you want to the `/data/db` location **before** the `VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb` directive.

#### Override the entrypoint

Assuming you have a tar archive named `mongo-data-db.tar` with the contents of the `/data/db` location from a mongo container having all the database and collections you want, you could use the following *Dockerfile* and *copy-initial-data-entry-point.sh*, you can build an image which will copy those data to the `/data/db` location every time the container is started. *This only make sense in a use case where such a container is used for a test suite which requiers the very same initial data everytime such a container is started as previous data are replaced with the inital data at each start.*

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mongo
COPY ./mongo-data-db.tar /mongo-data-db.tar
COPY ./copy-initial-data-entry-point.sh /
RUN chmod +x /copy-initial-data-entry-point.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/copy-initial-data-entry-point.sh"]
CMD ["mongod"]
```

**copy-initial-data-entry-point.sh:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

tar xf /mongo-data-db.tar -C /
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

---

In order to extract the contents of a `/data/db` from the volume of a mongo container named `my-mongo-container`, proceed as follow:

- stop the mongo container: `docker stop my-mongo-container`
- create a temporary container to produce the tar archive from the volume: `docker run --rm --volumes-from my-mongo-container -v $(pwd):/out ubuntu tar cvf /out/mongo-data-db.tar`

Note that this archive will be quite large as it contains the full contents of the mongo server data including indexes as described on the [mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/#back-up-with-cp-or-rsync)