# how to save a docker redis container

Tags: docker, redis

I'm having trouble creating an image of a docker redis container with the data in the redis database. At the moment I'm doing this:

```
docker pull redis
docker run --name my-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis
redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set hello world
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> save
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
docker stop my-redis
docker commit my-redis redis_with_data
docker run --name my-redis2 -p 6379:6379 -d redis_with_data
redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
(empty list or set)
```

I'm obviously not understanding something pretty basic here. Doesn't docker commit create a new image from an existing container?

---

okay, i've been doing some digging. The default redis image on hub.docker uses a data-volume which is then mounted at /data in a container. In order to share this volume between containers, you have to start a new container with the following argument:

```
docker run -d --volumes-from <name-of-container-you-want-the-data-from> \
  --name <new-container-name> -p 6379:6379 redis
```

Note that the order of the arguments is important, otherwise docker run will fail silently.

```
docker volume ls
```

will tell you which data volumes have already been created by docker on your computer. I haven't yet found a way to give these volumes a trivial name, rather than a long random string.

I also haven't yet found a way to mount a data-volume, but rather just use the `--volumes-from` command.

---

Okay. I now have it working, but it's cludgey.

With

```
docker volume ls
docker volume inspect <id of docker volume>
```

you can find the path of the docker volume on the local file-system.
You can then mount this in a new container as follows:

```
docker run -d -v /var/lib/docker/volumes/<some incredibly long string>/_data:/data \
   --name my-redis2 -p 6379:6379 redis
```

This is obviously not the way you're meant to do this. I'll carry on digging.

---

I put all that i've discovered upto now in a blog post: [my blog post on medium.com](https://medium.com/@ehrt74/what-you-have-to-know-before-creating-a-container-of-a-redis-docker-image-674f1c93ede0)

Maybe that will be useful for somebody

Answer (score 32):

Data in docker is not persistent, when you restart the container your data will be gone. To prevent this you have to share a map on the host machine with your container. When you container restarts it will get the data from the map on the host.

You can read more about it in the Docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#data-volumes

From the redis container docs:

Run redis-server

```
docker run -d --name redis -p 6379:6379 dockerfile/redis
```

Run redis-server with persistent data directory. (creates dump.rdb)

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 -v <data-dir>:/data --name redis dockerfile/redis
```

Run redis-server with persistent data directory and password.

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 -v <data-dir>:/data --name redis dockerfile/redis redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf --requirepass <password>
```

Source:
https://github.com/dockerfile/redis

Comment: I can stop and restart the container and the data persists. I'd like to have all the data inside the image, so I can just send somebody the image and they can run it.

Comment: You first stop the container(data gone on container) and then you commit it. Maybe you can commit before stopping it?

Comment: The data doesn't disappear when a container is stopped. it is (on my system at least) persistant.

Comment: Ah I think I understood your question wrong. You want to save the data inside the image. As far as I know that's not possible sorry :-(.

Comment: I've been digging a bit. It appears that the default redis image on docker-hub automatically creates a data volume. Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331651/how-can-i-backup-a-docker-container-with-its-data-volumes it appears to be quite difficult to actually access that data volume after it's been created.

Comment: Have you tried commiting before stopping the container?

Comment: Yep. it doesn't help :(

Comment: You're right, it does indeed make a data volume. I can't get it to work either. The ugly solution is to manually share the RDB files I think :-(.

Answer (score 4):

Using data volume and sharing RDB file manually is not ugly, actually that's what data volume is designed for, to separate data from container.

But if you really need/want to save data to image and share it that way, you can just change the redis working directory from volume `/data` to somewhere else:

- Option 1 is changing `--dir` when start the redis container:

  ```
  docker run -d redis --dir /tmp
  ```

  Then you can follow your steps to create new image. Note that only `/tmp` could be used by this method due to permission issue.
- Option 2 is creating a new image with changed `WORKDIR`:

  ```
  FROM redis

  RUN mkdir /opt/redis && chown redis:redis /opt/redis
  WORKDIR /opt/redis
  ```

  Then `docker build -t redis-new-image` and use this image to do your job.