# Docker mysql image - move internal container DB to the volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have started using docker with docker-compose where I have the database defined. Since I did not have volumes defined in the configuration (my mistake), the database has been created inside the container and now next time when I run docker-pull, I will get this database re-created causing my data loss. What would be the best way to move the data out of the container without losing the data?

```
  db:
    image: "mydbimage"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "jirio"
      MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:5.6
ADD schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
```

Comment: You can find all the files in `/var/lib/docker/` in your host filesystem if you haven't deleted your container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't lose your data if you run `docker pull mysql:5.6` since you were running an instance of `mydbimage`.

Also, there is no data loss unless you remove the container with `docker rm -v`.  Docker Compose does not remove volumes, either, unless you run `docker-compose rm -v`.

Get the name or ID of the container that was running mysql:5.6 with `docker ps -a` and run:

`docker run --rm --volumes-from $container ubuntu tar -zcvf- /var/lib/mysql > /tmp/backup.tar.gz`

Note: Substitute `$container` with the name or ID of the container.

Then you can decompress the tarball to some location on the host, say /var/mysql, update `mydbimage` if you want, and add this line to your Docker Compose YAML:

```
volumes:
  -v /var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

NOTE: A `docker commit` never saves the volumes in a container.

Comment: That seems more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the container (exited and stopped) with that data, your first step would be to commit it as an image in order to *not* loose the data.
See [`docker container commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_commit/). That will save the container content, not its volume... but there was no volume in it anyway.

If your container has defined its own internal volume, see if "[How can I backup a Docker-container with its data-volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41279845/6309)" applies to your case.

Then you can run a new container based on that committed image (with a shell as a command), this time [creating and mounting a new data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container).
Once running, in that shell, you can zip/copy your data into the volume path (which will actually write onto your data volume container)

Finally, you can reuse that data volume container into your existing `docker-compose.yml`

---

Knowing that the OP's image is [docker mysql:5.6](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql), its [Dockerfile defines its own internal volume](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/2bbab7b691b582e2df99dbd16525608adbff016e/5.6/Dockerfile#L62), which is not backed up by default.

In that case, if the container is still running, the easiest approach is to make a [dump of the database](https://gist.github.com/spalladino/6d981f7b33f6e0afe6bb):

```
# Backup
docker exec CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=root DATABASE > backup.sql
```

Once you have that data, you can run the image again, this time with an host folder mounted a volume, or with a data volume container.

See "[MySQL on Docker: Building the Container Image](https://severalnines.com/blog/mysql-docker-building-container-image)"

[image: http://severalnines.com/sites/default/files/blog/node_4752/image09.png]

But if the container is stopped, you cannot execute command in it ([issue 30361](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30361))

Comment: A `docker commit` never saves the volumes of a container.

Comment: @RicardoBranco the all point of this question was that the container had *no* volume at all. The goal of the commit is to save whatever was written in the container.

Comment: It depends if the original image (mysql, postgres, etc.) defines a volume.

Comment: @RicardoBranco possible, but the "Since I did not have volumes defined" told me otherwise. Let us wait for the OP's comment on this.

Comment: @RicardoBranco I have added a link to a volume backup process, in case the OP's container *did* include its own volume. That should cover both scenario.

Comment: Guys, thanks for answer. my configuration had no volumes at all.

Comment: @ser OK. Hence my suggestion to freeze and commit the container. Still, check if the base image for that container has its own internal volume

Comment: @VonC thank you. Could you please let me know what exact steps and comomands I should invoke since the end going is to have running everything with docker-compose again.

Comment: @ser first, do you still have your container with the data you want to preserve?

Comment: @VonC yes I have that container

Comment: @SergeiLedvanov Did you manage to commit it as a new image, as described in the answer?

Comment: @SergeiLedvanov and is your container still running? (see my edited answer)