# backup and restore docker application from my host laptop to an other laptop

Tags: docker, odoo

Please I need to backup and restore the docker application of my host laptop to another laptop, because in the first machine (Ubuntu 18.04), I have docker installed, and the inside docker a lot of containers (odoo and postgres), I have to back up the docker application and restore it in second machine without losing any container and its own files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [How can I backup a Docker container with its data volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331651/how-can-i-backup-a-docker-container-with-its-data-volumes). An answer shows how to backup and restore images, containers, and data volumes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I backup a Docker-container with its data-volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331651/how-can-i-backup-a-docker-container-with-its-data-volumes)

Comment: You might take this opportunity to restructure your setup so that all of the data that's important to be saved is stored outside the container (in host directories or named volumes).  `docker rm` should be pretty routine and not have any real impact on your data.  The answers in the linked question have some good suggestions too.