# Unable to backup docker volumne

Tags: docker

I'm following the offical docker guide from [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to backup a docker volume. I'm also aware of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331651/how-can-i-backup-a-docker-container-with-its-data-volumes) however I'm still running into errors. Running the following command:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from dbstore -v $(pwd):/backup ny_db_1 tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata
```

No matter what image name or container name or container id I put, I get the following error:

```
Unable to find image 'ny_db_1:latest' locally
```

**The volume I want to backup:**

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               ny_postgres_data
```

My containers:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
39e71e660eda        postgres:10.1-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 days ago          Up 23 minutes       0.0.0.0:5434->5433/tcp   ny_db_1
```

How do I backup my volume?

**Update:**

I tried the following but ran into a new error:

```
$ docker run --rm --volumes-from 39e71e660eda -v $(pwd):/backup postgres:10.1-alpine tar:local cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 145: exec: tar:local: not found
```

Comment: `ny_db_1` is a container name, the `docker run` syntax is `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]` - replace that container name with an `IMAGE[:TAG]` that has `tar` installed (i.e. `ubuntu:18.04`) and you should be good. The idea is to run a new container from an image mounting the volumes from an existing container then to execute a command inside the new container to backup the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this command here:

```
docker run -it --rm -v ny_postgres_data:/volume -v /tmp:/backup ny_db_1 \
    tar -cjf /backup/ny_postgres_data -C /volume ./
```

Answer (score 3):

The `docker run` syntax is `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]` - `ny_db_1` is the name of your container, `docker` will attempt to use the `IMAGE` "`ny_db_1`" which does not exist hence the error: "`Unable to find image 'ny_db_1:latest' locally`" (`latest` is the default `[:TAG]` if none is specified).

`--volumes-from` will [mount volumes from the specified container(s)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) into a new container spawned from `IMAGE[:TAG]` for example: `docker run --rm --volumes-from db -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu:18.04 tar czvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata`

**Note**: if you're backing up a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database then imho you'd be better off using the appropriate tools to backup and restore the database for example:

Backup using `pg_dumpall`:

```
docker run --rm \
    --name db-backup \
    --entrypoint pg_dumpall \
    --volume ${PWD}/backup:/backup \
    --volumes-from db \
    postgres:9 --host /var/run/postgresql --username postgres --clean --oids --file /backup/db.dump
```

Restore using `psql`:

```
docker run --rm -it \
    -v ${PWD}/backup:/restore \
    --name restore \
    postgres:10.1-alpine

docker exec restore psql \
    --host /var/run/postgresql \
    --username postgres \
    --file /restore/db.dump postgres

docker rename restore NEW_NAME
```