# Backup, restore, or migrate data volumes using Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, backup, docker-for-windows, docker-volume

I am trying to backup the data of a mysql docker container volume.
I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331651/how-can-i-backup-a-docker-container-with-its-data-volumes), but it didn't work for me yet. I use git bash, so I can use unix tools.

The problem is, I cannot access the volume data, which is on the docker VM (disk image location is `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\DockerDesktop.vhdx`).

I tried

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from mysql_1 -v /$(pwd):/backup busybox tar cvf ./backup/backup_sql.tar /var/lib/docker/volumes/<some hash>/_data`.
```

which exited with error

```
tar: C:/Program Files/Git/var/lib/docker/volumes/<some hash>/_data: No such file or directory
tar: error exit delayed from previous errors
```

`/var/lib/docker/volumes/<some hash>/_data` is the Source of the mounted volume as given by command `docker inspect mysql_1`.

An empty tar file ./backup_sql.tar was created.

Has anyone succeeded doing a backup and restore of a docker volume with docker for windows and is willing to share?

Answer (score 0):

For this command use cmd with the following command:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from mysql_1 -v %cd%:/backup busybox tar cvf ./backup/backup_sql.tar /var/lib/docker/volumes/<some hash>/_data`.
```