# Backup docker volume while running

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Problem:**

I'd like to create regular backups of a docker volume used by a running docker container.

**Partial solutions:**

If I shut down the container using the volume, I found these solutions:

- Save to .tar like:
  `docker run --rm -v some_volume:/volume -v /tmp:/backup alpine tar -cjf 
  /backup/some_archive.tar.bz2 -C /volume ./`
  (Source: https://medium.com/@loomchild/backup-restore-docker-named-volumes-350397b8e362)
- Stackoverflow solution:
  [How can I backup a Docker-container with its data-volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331651/how-can-i-backup-a-docker-container-with-its-data-volumes)

**Question**:

Using either docker or also docker-compose, how do I backup a volume, without any downtime of the app container using the volume?

Comment: Those same solutions should still work; you should just be aware that there might be things like pid files that could cause problems on restore, and that the application might keep some of its state in memory until it's cleanly shut down.