# Back up Docker container's volumes correctly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, backup, docker-volume

I was wondering if I was backing up my container's volumes correctly.

## Info

```
System :
NAS Synology with docker App

What I use to build my containers :
Docker-compose
```

## Process

This is how I do :

First I build my containers with `docker-compose up -d` :

```
docker-compose.yaml
...
  nginx:
    image: 'jlesage/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    container_name: Nginx-jlesage
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: ${GB_TZ}
    volumes:
      - '/volume1/docker/nginx/:/config:rw'
    network_mode: host
...
```

I've around 10-15 containers (they are apps or databases)

Every container has it own folder in my `/volume/docker/` folder.

Then in order to back up any container data, I simply stop every running container and I copy/paste the `/docker/` folder somewhere else (not on my NAS)

## Restore data

If I ever need to restore one of my container's data (dead NAS or corrupted file), I would delete the container, delete its data and copy/paste my back up at the same place, then rebuild my container with `docker-compose up -d`.

## Conclusion

I've seen so much complicated way (like this one [How can I backup a Docker-container with its data-volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331651/how-can-i-backup-a-docker-container-with-its-data-volumes#:%7E:text=back%20up%20docker%20data%20volumes,data%20for%20a%20MySQL%20server.)) to do it and I can't figure if my solution is horrible or not and if my data are in danger or not.

I tried deleting my docker folder, then restoring everything using my method, it worked and I'm confused and scared about missing something.

Comment: You're using a bind-mounted host directory, and backing up that directory should be enough (doubly true if you've tested the restore already).  Named volumes are the more complex case.

Answer (score 0):

I use [offen/docker-volume-backup](https://github.com/offen/docker-volume-backup) you add to your docker compose file and use it to periodically backup volumes used in the stack. It can also disable other containers for the duration of the backup, do a tarball of their volume to backup destination and start them back up.