# Docker: clean up all stopped containers except data-only containers

Tags: docker

What is the Docker way to clean up all stopped Docker containers but retain data-only containers?

- `docker rm $(docker ps -qa -f status=exited)` removes these too!

How to clean up the according images?

Comment: How do you define a data-only container ?

Comment: It is a concept where a container does not run a lengthy process, but only defines a volume used by other containers via `--volumes-from`. In that way, these data containers do not need to be updated when an application changes and can be treated separately. (see related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21597463/1725096)

Comment: Update note: the introduction of **named volumes** renders the concept of **data-only containers** obsolete now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [Mykolas proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27932919/1725096) I introduced a naming convention requiring all data-only containers to be suffixed by `-data`.

**To remove all stopped containers, except those named `*-data`:**

```
docker ps -a -f status=exited | grep -v '\-data *$'| awk '{if(NR>1) print $1}' | xargs -r docker rm
```

**To remove all unused images afterwards:**

```
docker rmi $(docker images -qa -f dangling=true)
```

(the images used by the data-only containers are retained)

Answer (score 5):

In general there is no definitive way to distinguish `data-only` from other containers. If you wish them to survive your cleansing, you could probably design a certain name scheme and have more elaborate scripts that wouldn't remote containers with name, say, starting with `data-`.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can, in the `docker run` command of all your data-only container add `a  -e "type=data-only"`, and then filter based on this criteria, either with a grep or with a `docker inspect`  example, I start a container with `sudo docker run -it -e type=data-only ubuntu bash
root@f7e9ea4efbd9:/#` and then `sudo docker inspect  -f "{{ .Config.Env }}" f7e` shows 
`[type=data-only PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin]`

Comment: simpler, `sudo docker inspect  -f "{{ index .Config.Env 0}}" f7e`
prints `type=data-only`