# How to access data from a file in a docker volume

Tags: docker

I am relatively new to `Docker`. I am struggling to fetch sensitive data on file which is set a docker volume.

This is how i have setup directory structure in `Dockerfile`

```
RUN mkdir /env
RUN touch /env/config.json
```

This my volume setup in `docker-compose.yml`

```
volumes:
      - ./main_app:/main_app
      - ./env/config.json:/env/config.json
```

I am trying to access data in `config.json` in `Django settings` file as shown

```
with open('/env/config.json') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)
```

Now when i try to run `docker-compose run` i get the following error

```
unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

What could be the issue with my setup?

Comment: Does the configuration file exist on the host, in that exact path?  (If it didn't, Docker would have created a directory, and then you'd get that error.)

Comment: I am adding the file with this command ```RUN touch /env/config.json```

Comment: So the image should contain an empty file; and when you start the container, you are trying to mount something on the host over that file.  Does the file `./env/config.json` exist on the host?

Answer (score 0):

You are tyring to mount a file as a volume and need to change

```
 - ./env/config.json:/env/config.json
```

to

```
 - ./env:/env
```

Comment: I modified as shown but then Django is throwing the following error ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/env/config.json'```

Comment: Sorry about that! Please try to run your image interactively to see if the files are where you expect them to be by running the image with ```docker run -it ...```. Please see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/ for more details about running images interactively.

Comment: When i run ```ls``` i get ```ls: cannot access '/env': No such file or directory```

Comment: Strange... should work. See f.x. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910980/924036. Sorry, dont have any other ideas at the moment.