# What is the difference between these two docker volumes?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

What is the difference between these two volumes in docker? Will they mount same directory or a directory above? I am so confused.

Also, Why is it when I run a container with latest tag and without latest tag, they show different content. Attaching screenshots for more clarity. Any help or hint is appreciated.

```
version: '2'

services:

  jenkins:
    volumes:
       - jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home
    networks:
      - jenkinsnet
    build: ./
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '50000:50000'

networks:
  jenkinsnet:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  jenkins_data:
```

and
**docker-compose.yml with ./ before jenkins_data**

```
version: '2'

services:

  jenkins:
    volumes:
       - ./jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home
    networks:
      - jenkinsnet
    build: ./
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '50000:50000'

networks:
  jenkinsnet:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  jenkins_data:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
WORKDIR /var/jenkins_home/
USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install wget && apt-get install sudo
RUN sudo apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN sudo apt update -y
# smartcheck jre download

RUN sudo wget https://github.com/gouravthakur39/smartcheck-jre-solidity-scan/blob/main/smartcheck-2.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
RUN touch abcd
#Update the username and password
ENV JENKINS_USER oodles
ENV JENKINS_PASS oodles

#id_rsa.pub file will be saved at /root/.ssh/
RUN ssh-keygen -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -N ''

# allows to skip Jenkins setup wizard
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false

# Jenkins runs all grovy files from init.groovy.d dir
# use this for creating default admin user
COPY default-user.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/

VOLUME /var/jenkins_home
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Compose Relative paths vs Docker volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907558/docker-compose-relative-paths-vs-docker-volume)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `jenkins_data`, you're using a named volume which refer to the volume declared at the end of the compose file in `volumes` section, and the corresponding folder will be created in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`.

When using `./jenkins_data` you're using an host path volume which refer to the the folder `jenkins_data` next to your compose file.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes

Comment: zigarn is right, here are the relevant key words: docker volumes (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) vs. docker bind mounts (https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

Comment: Also, latest and lts tags are different images in the docker hub

Comment: does using ./jenkins_data create bind mount? @zigarn

Comment: yep - it's a valid path