# Save docker Mongo container with all the data and export it

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-machine

I have created a docker image with a container of Mongo.

My database is filled with data, up to 35 GB.

I want to be able to export it (tar file for example) with all the data inside, and to import to another docker-machine without losing any data.

When using docker save, I couldn't find any information on the statut of saving up data ...

What is the best method to save a fully functionnal container and import it to another docker-machine ?

Comment: You want to save a container or image? The approach is different is each case.

Comment: Hello @yamenk.
I have create a new container from the official mongo image. From this container, I have created a full database (~400M of documents).
I did **not** commit anything. In short, I want to be able to export/import this database from computer to another computer.

(New to docker/mongo, sorry in advance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To export a container:

```
docker export --output="container.tar" <container-name>
```

This will export your container to container.tar which can be imported back on another machine using:

```
docker import container.tar <container-name>.
```

**However**, as stated in the [docker export docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/#extended-description):

> The docker export command does not export the contents of volumes
>   associated with the container. If a volume is mounted on top of an
>   existing directory in the container, docker export will export the
>   contents of the underlying directory, not the contents of the volume.

Now mongo exposes `/data/db` and `/data/configdb` as volumes. Thus they will not be exported with the tar ball. Thus the data and config won't be in the tar :(

```
VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb
```

What you need to do in order to get this data is either one of the follow:

1. [How to port data-only volumes from one host to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597463/how-to-port-data-only-volumes-from-one-host-to-another)
2. Copy these folders form inside the container manually and copy them back to the new container when your import it from the tar.

   docker cp :/data/db ./data
   docker cp :/data/configdb ./config

Copy these folder to the new host, then import the tarred container and finally copy back these folder into the container

```
docker cp data/* <new-container>:/data/db
docker cp config/* <new-container>:/data/configdb
```

Answer (score 0):

To view the status of docker save u need to use --output  ex:. docker save --output imagename > imagename.tar.   u cannot save container only image can be saved.  In order to save container data u need to commit n launch from committed container