# Exporting a Docker Container and Volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have some academic code that I want to share in a self-contained environment, so that various experimental results can be replicated.

My approach so far is a docker container, with a few build scripts to add the required dependencies, and a volume containing the actual code and data.

The Dockerfile seems easy to share, and this will recreate the state of the container; then, someone else would need to start a docker container with the volume, so I need to export the volume.

I've tried the steps in [Backup a container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597463/how-to-port-data-only-volumes-from-one-host-to-another), but I'm not sure exactly what needs to happen.

The volume is called `offline-simon-vol` and I started a container `testcont` using

`docker run -v offline-simon-vol --name testcont ubuntu /bin/bash`

and then I tried to run

`docker run --rm --volumes-from testcont -v $(pwd)/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup.backup.tar offline-simon-vol`

which executes without error, but I have no idea where the backed up volume is!

I can't find the documentation on what all of these flags do. As far as I can tell, this is starting a new instance of the "ubuntu" container, but loading all the volumes that are in `testcont`.

I don't know what `$(pwd)/backup` is doing; the answer I linked seems to say that this is the location where the exported volume will appear, but nothing new appears in the working directory.

The `tar` command at the end should be compressing `offline-simon-vol` to `/backup.backup.tar` (I think). But `/backup.backup.tar` doesn't appear in the root directory when this command finishes. I also don't understand why the output filename should start with `/backup`, rather than, e.g., the working directory.

Finally, the answer I linked has `/data` instead of the volume's name as the final word, but when I use `/data` it just gives me a `tar: /data: Cannot stat: No such file or directory` error.

What can I do to find the exported volume, or export it into a specific place? Also, is this the best way to export my code and data for reproducibility?

Comment: If I wanted to reproduce your experiment and understand your results, I would likely want to see the original source code, not a built and packaged Docker image.  A GitHub repository containing the experimental code and the scripts to load or regenerate the data would probably be better for this particular case.

Comment: The source code is definitely essential, but that's all going into the docker volume. The main issue is that the code runs Microsoft's quantum development kit, which tends to be tricky to install (and also changes frequently, which Docker doesn't help with).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `docker run --rm --volumes-from testcont -v $(pwd)/backup ubuntu tar cvf  /backup.backup.tar offline-simon-vol` command is:

- Running an Ubuntu container with a volumes mounted from `testcont`
- Compressing things from `offline-simon-vol` *within the container* to `/backup.backup.tar` *within the container as well*.
- Mounting the host's `<current dir>/backup` (`$(pwd)/backup`)
  to the same path in the container.

Effectively, *none of the things in this command will result with a backed up directory on the host* because:

- `offline-simon-vol` is probably not the right path *within the container*
- `/backup.backup.tar` *within the container* is not a mapped volume of the host
- Nothing is being written to the actual host's mounted directory (`$(pwd)/backup`).

Anyways, to the solution:

- Use `docker run --rm --volumes-from testcont -v $(pwd)/backup:/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /path/to/offline-simon-vol`
- Make sure that `/path/to/offline-simon-vol` is the correct path to the mounted volume *within the container*.

Comment: I don't know where the volume was saved to in the original command I used, but I just ran another container and specified the location of the volume. Then the command you gave prints all the files in the volume to the console, and produces a folder called "backup" in the working directory, but the folder is empty.

Comment: You can do `docker inspect testcont` to see where the volumes are mounted on the container. Look for `offline-simon-vol` in the output.

Comment: "backup" folder in your current host's dir should have the file `backup.tar` that contains all the compressed volume files (if you don't see anything, try `sudo ls` since the file is owned by root.